# Typescript - Proper way to get parent from child

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance, parent-child

So, my question is: **Is there a way to get a parent instance from a child instance in typescript?**

I know that you can cast a child into its parent, but the thing is that the extra child properties are still present in the parent, they are just hidden..

[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeAoavrzGQFNoBeaAIgRTQoG4sBfLLUSGAEQHsBzaIgB4AXIvAAmMaqnTY8+QiXIVuPejjwAHLgHciAJzLQA5ACEwegNZGGzVl3gQh0C4fhFt0FQAoAlA2D2jtBihi6QcEjS-oFcIEQAdCC8XmLxWrp6fkA) a minimal reproductible example:

```js
class Animal {
    name = "Animal";
}

class Kid extends Dog {
    name = "Dog";
    power = 'Bark';
}

const a = new Animal();
const d = a as Dog;
console.log(d.power);
```

In this code, the linter is not happy with the `d.power`, but it still compiles and it works just fine.

So is there a better way to do this, without redefining a new parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Kid` class is just inheriting `Daddy`. When you say `k as Daddy` (even if this does nothing, since `k instanceof Daddy` is already true), your are just saying "treat `k` knowing it has all `Daddy` properties and methods".

But in the end, `k` is a Kid instance. Your classes naming shows maybe you don't full understand inheritance, since they are not "Parent" and "Child", it's more like "Animal" vs "Dog" or "Person" vs "Daddy". Generally speaking outside of programming world, we can be sure a Kid is not a Daddy.

Comment: True, I understand that, and yes, my naming is incorrect, I was influenced by how we call them "parent" and "children" class when we speak about inheritance, even though, as you said, it's an `Animal - Dog` relationship, and not a `Daddy - Kid`.